# C#, make "something" move forward all the time in 2d array?

Tags: c#

I was working with a 2D array and I struggled figuring out how to make an object move forward "all the time" in a console app. By that I mean like every frame or so.

In unity we have the "Update" method were you can make it go forward each frame, but what if you make an ordinary snake game in a console app?

Is the only option to make a timer and then every 0,5 of a second move horizontal 
/ vertical? Or is there some kind of function implemented for this issue?

Comment: A timer would be the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't anything special about Unity's `Update` method other than it being part of their render cycle.

If you need something to be updated periodically; a `Timer` is the appropriate solution.

Comment: Curious, what is it that triggers Unity's Update() to fire?

Comment: @DaveInCaz Not having investigated their source code... I would imagine a fast timer invokes their draw loop, and `Update` is called there right before `Draw`

Comment: https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/12/23/1k-update-calls/ see section "How Update is called"

Comment: @MuhammadMehdi Can you be more specific? I was just answering the question as to what an appropriate approach to periodic execution is.

Comment: If you put question with code.it is ease for understanding what you want to move

Comment: Thanks! But an idea just hit me, can't you just use a while loop with a "System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500) in it? and then each 0,5 seconds update the position? I guess a timer would be better though!

Comment: @MuhammadMehdi I get the feeling you are trying to address the OP

Comment: @JacksonMacDislike Your solution will block the calling thread the whole time; a `Timer` will not. Very important if that thread is the UI thread and you don't want your app to appear unresponsive.

Comment: @MuhammadMehdi It really sounds like you have a separate question. Please ask it as such if so.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Ok thanks! I will look up a Timer then :)